# Cordova minSdk version not working

Tags: android, cordova

We try to set the minSdk version of our android app.

We did everything like edit the manifest, and append:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

To the config.xml.

Everything looks fine from the outside. But after building our release apk, and decompiling it with apktool, there is no minSdk and targetSdk in it anymore.

Is there anybody who nows how to do this properly? We are preparing for a major event and this buggy cordova crap is not helping. Is there any way to set it manually?

Or should we really decompile, append the string and recompile? This is pathetic.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? Decompilation is by no means perfect.  When I adjust the min sdk in one of my projects (my device is Jellybean -- 16) to something higher, the apk won't install as intended.

Comment: Just look at the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml. Check for a line like `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` (yeah, mine's there)